# "Disconnected" phantom B: drive causing problems

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, unmount

On one of our servers, a drive mapping has suddenly appeared (across all users).  The drive mapping is invalid, and is causing spurious error and warning messages.  It is a mount to "B:" (which is hard to produce in any circumstance).  An attempt to "disconnect" the network drive results in the error message:

"B:, connected to =, could not be disconnected because an error has occurred: This network connection does not exist."

Does anyone know either (1) what might have caused such a strange mapping (so that we can prevent it in future) or (2) how to get rid of the phantom mapping?  I have not tested if it persists across a re-boot, simply because this is a large production server that we can only reboot on weekends.

The server is running Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Some other details: there is no entry in either `HKCU\Network` or `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2` corresponding to this mount - nor would I expect there to be, because the mount is across all users.

Thanks.

Comment: I get this too on Windows 10 Pro. Some software might think drive B: is a floppy drive

Comment: Your last name is McIntosh, you should switch to Apple lol

Comment: Command line doesn't work either

net use /delete S
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.